# Copying contents from 1 table into another except for matching record(s)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question about running a particular type of query.
Here's the example: I have 2 tables X and Y

```
Table X
1@abc.com
2@abc.com
3@abc.com
```

I now want to move EVERYTHING into table Y.
So now, Table Y looks just like Table X

I now delete everything from Table X, except for 1@abc.com
So the new Table X looks like this:

```
Table X
1@abc.com
```

Let's say that I did this accidentally and I now want to move everything from Table Y back into X except for matching records (which, in this case, would 1@abc.com)

How would I go about this?

Comment: lol.. No. I can't delete anything as this is a production environment. Obviously, my example is oversimplified, so I'm really looking for the logic here.

Comment: @John K. - The OP has joined 20 days ago. Give him a break.

Comment: thanks, Oded. I've now learned how to accept answers. I'll take care of that 0%  :)

Comment: thanks for the feedback, djacobson. I will start this practice moving forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something close to the below ought to do it.  Watch for NULLs, though - you'll need to ensure that the conditions on the LEFT JOIN cope with these.

```
INSERT INTO X
SELECT *
FROM Y
LEFT JOIN X
ON X.field1 = Y.field1
AND X.field2 = Y.field2
AND ...
WHERE X.field1 IS NULL
```

Comment: ...Oded's answer is much less effort.  :)

Comment: @Ray - in the future, please specify _versions_ in your question.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [`EXCEPT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) relational operator:

```
INSERT INTO X
SELECT * FROM Y
  EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM X
```

There are complementary `INTERSECT` and the much better known [`UNION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) operators as well.

Comment: (SELECT * FROM Y) EXCEPT (SELECT * FROM X)?

Comment: @Will A - Yup... I was too quick ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why not delete everything in table X and then simply copy everything from table Y back into table X?

Comment: See my comment above. Basically, production environment. So no deletions allowed.

Comment: so... then how did table x data get deleted?  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need the EXCEPT keyword

```
INSERT TableX
SELECT * FROM TableY
EXCEPT
SELECT ID FROM TABLEX
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I will make one assumption for ease of demonstrating a solution.  That assumption is simply that X and Y have a primary key column named id.

```
INSERT INTO X (id, col1, col2, ...col(n))
   SELECT Y.id, Y.col1, Y.col2, ...Y.col(n)
   FROM Y
   LEFT OUTER JOIN X
   ON X.id = Y.id
   WHERE X.id is NULL;
```

This method inserts the missing rows into X from Y.  For a good example of this, take a look at the book *Beginning T-SQL 2008* by Kathi Kellenberger, pages 190-191.